# Reading values of primitive type in to variables from standard input

Tags: c++, inputstream

Suppose that I have the following definition of variables that i attempt to read values in to from standard input.

```
int ia = 3;
double da = 0;

std::cin >> ia >> da;
```

Now I type the following values in standard input, `-4.23 -5.01`

If I now print `ia` and `da` , `da` is .23 and `ia` is -4.

Why did C++ split -4.23 in to integer component and floating point component, in other words why did .23 remain in the input stream for subsequent reads ? Wouldn't -4.23 simply be truncated in to -4 and then read in to `ia` ?

Now a different scenario, suppose I have the same piece of code as above but this time I enter the number `.23` in to the standard input stream (which is just the console) `ia` stores 0 (ok this seems to follow the above behavior) but then `da` contains 0 this time ? Seems like in this situation `0.23` was truncated and read in as 0 and .23 did not read in to `da` as it did above.

I'm having trouble understanding what exactly is supposed to happen in these situations. Two different things are happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why did C++ split -4.23 in to integer component and floating point component, in other words why did .23 remain in the input stream for subsequent streams.

You told the stream that the input is going to contain an integer and a double, and it did its best at parsing the input to what you have specified.

The stream started reading an `int`, read `-4`, realized that it cannot make further progress reading the number when it saw a dot `.`, and stopped at that. After that you told C++ to read a double. It saw `.23` followed by a space, and interpreted it like a perfectly legitimate `double` value.

> suppose I have the same piece of code as above but this time I enter the number .23 in to the standard input stream (which is just the console) `ia` stores 0 (OK this seems to follow the above behavior) but then `da` contains 0 this time

This is because when you asked for an integer input, the stream could not legitimately parse anything into `ia`. This puts the stream into an error state, meaning that no further input is possible until the error flag has been reset.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cin >> ia
```

skips any whitespace characters. Then, it tries to extract an `int` from `std::cin`. If it finds a character that cannot be used as part of an `int`, it stops.

In your case, the `.` after `-4` cannot be used as part of an `int`. Hence, the extraction stops there.  After that `.23 -5.01` is still left on the stream.

Then kicks in the `>> da` part. Since `.23` is a valid `double` that is extracted and stored in `da`. The extraction stops at the whitespace. After that, `-5.01` is still left on the input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Easy.  You told the code to input a decimal value, and it did.  The '.' in `-4.23` is not a integer digit, so it stopped and assigned "-4" to the integer.

The stream pointer is at ".23", which is a valid `double` number; so it assigned everything up to the space to the variable.  So your `double` variable contains ".23".

Try changing the variables so they are of the same type or changing the input data so the first item is an integer.